# What WebDriver is the correct one to use to test for UC Browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, uc-browser

UC Browser is popular in China and India. There does not appear to be a Selenium WebDriver to use with it. What is the closest alternative?

Answer (score 0):

According to a [blog post](http://www.ucweb.com/desktop/blog/UC-Browser-For-Windows-Like-Chrome-With-Extras) on their site, UC Browser for Windows is based on Chrome. So, using chromedriver should be good enough.

But, the browser gained popularity in the first place (in the mobile browser segment) by serving heavily compressed pages from their own servers instead of the actual web server for the page you requested (which meant no client side scripts could run, not sure how it works nowadays). Considering this, if you'd want to test with such features turned on, [Opera has a turbo mode](https://www.opera.com/computer/features/fast-browser) which is similar to what UC Browser for Windows does (based purely on how it looks and feels during usage). [Opera webdrivers](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) available. And, since Opera is based on chrome too, I'd say that is your best bet.